# Peg Thing, Clojure for the brave and true

Tags: clojure

I am going throw the 5th chapter and trying to implement Peg Thing. I downloaded code to see how it works, but when I start the game with "lein run" i got this in my cmd:

```
      a<-[34mO-[Om
b<-34mO<-[Om C<-[34mO<-[Om...
```

and proportionaly the same for the rest three rows. Insted this, I expected to get something like:

```
        a0
      b0   c0
    d0  e0   f0
  g0  h0  i0   j0
k0  l0  m0  n0   o0
```

Can somebody help about this?

Comment: if you don't include some code, or a link, you are unlikely to get much help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember, Clojure for Brave and True uses `colorize` function to output colored symbols on the terminal. It does so by inserting special symbols to terminal output that should have been treated as color by a terminal. Seems that either those sequences are wrong or your terminal does not support colors.
To fix that you can change `render-pos` function and replace `colorize` calls with simple value return. E.g.

```
(defn render-pos
  [board pos]
  (str (nth letters (dec pos))
       (if (get-in board [pos :pegged])
         "0"                             ;;(colorize "0" :blue)
         "-")))                          ;;(colorize "-" :red))))
```

You can find out more about terminal color output [here.](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)